# How to get Html Element's Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to extract the text part of the html.

If I have `<p>ABCD</p>`

I want the out put to be `ABCD`

Something like,

```
var html='<p>ABCD</p>';
var str = convertToString(html);
```

Hope, I will need a function which converts from html to string, or maybe extract string from it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to extract the text content from the string

```
var html = '<p>ABCD</p>';
var str = $(html).text();//get a jQuery reference and then read its text content
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = '<p>ABCD</p>';
var str = $(html).text();
console.log(str);
```

This would do the task.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a `selector(id,class name etc)` of get the required element of `DOM` and use `.text()` to get `text part of the html.`

HTML

```
<p>ABCD</p>
```

Jquery

```
var str = $('p').text();  // $('p') "p" is a selector to select p element(s)
console.log(str)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oc9yaf3q/)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript way

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
alert(txt);
```

```html
<p id="demo">Test text</p>
```

Comment: Your answer retrieves the HTML content of the element. The OP wants the text content, which is accessed by the `.textContent` property.